Extruding Edges (Coffee Bag Sides)
after encountering too many errors in the surface of my first attempt, I have now decided to completely remodel my coffee bag. I would like to pull the selected edge inward. However, when I try to do it with G, or even with E for extrusion, I only move the line, but not the entire surface. How can I accomplish this?

That is what happens:

I am trying to create something like this:


Thank you in advance. I am thankful for any tips and hints.
If I am not on the right path, I am open to any suggestions. Thank you.

I'm not a pro at editing vertices, but have you tried selecting the entire face?

Yes, then unfortunately the entire face moves evenly.

Those parts are not topologically good either, you need to give it thickness:

You could begin with an inset (press i then B for Boundary so that it sticks to the mirror axis):

Then extrude this part:

Add some topology and push this edge (after that give your object a Subdivsion Surface modifier, add some support edge loops where you want your edges to stay sharp, etc):

